# is there a way to delete or replace any row on my data that it's type is 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 1200000 rows x 96 columns dataframe, they are numbers, except for a few of them whose types are date and time.

The Question is:

I'd like to remove any row whose type is `datetime.datetime` and convert the rest to float if they are number but their type is string
[image]

Comment: please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help getting you the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the results you requested

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column1' : [123213123, '2022-01-01', '0111'],
    'Column2' : ['2022-01-01', 111, '21398021']
})

for x in range(0, len(df.columns)):
    df[df.columns[x]] = df[df.columns[x]].astype(str)
    df[df.columns[x]] = np.where(df[df.columns[x]].str.contains('-'), np.nan, df[df.columns[x]])
    df[df.columns[x]] = df[df.columns[x]].astype(float)
    
df
```

If you are wanting to delete any row who had a date string in that row you can simply replace the last line of the previous code with `df = df.dropna()` and that will remove all rows that contain an np.nan from before